# How to replace Table Loader

Tags: sas

During loading "Table loader" (replace) step I recived Java Error.
Is there is a way to replace mentioned above "Table loader" e.g Userr Written code to define there code to replace my dataset?

Comment: Hi; I added the [tag:sas-dis] tag assuming you are asking about SAS Data Integration Studio or related products (DQS, etc.).  If you're not, please specify more information.  Either way, please show the error code and provide more information about what you are doing.

Comment: Why wouldn't you fix the Java issue as it likely will cause other issues?